# Admin access with tank_auth in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I'm using [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) and my project will support two access type: "normal user" and "admin". I looked at the tank auth database and there is a "isadmin" field, so I believe that it's possible redirect to `/admin` or `/user` when I log in to my system.

How can I do this? I only see `is_logged_in()`.

I already saw this: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/207245/ but I want only a redirect to `/user` or `/admin` URL depending if admin or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tank_Auth doesn't come with any kind of user group or permission features built in. I'm not sure where you saw a field called `isadmin` because it doesn't seem to be part of the [current default setup](https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth/blob/master/schema.sql) and I couldn't even find the word "admin" in the package files.

This is the easiest solution I can think of:

Add the `is_admin` field you mentioned to the users table and manage it manually.

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD COLUMN `is_admin` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

Working with the way Tank_Auth currently does, you'll be reading the user data from the session, so you'll have to add it to the session on login.

```
// Tank_Auth.php Line 71
$this->ci->session->set_userdata(array(
    'is_admin'  => (bool) $user->is_admin, // added
    'user_id'   => $user->id,
    'username'  => $user->username,
    'status'    => ($user->activated == 1) ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED,
));
```

Then add your own function to the library:

```
function is_admin()
{
    return $this->logged_in() && $this->ci->session->userdata('is_admin') === TRUE;
}
```

Then you'll have to add this to the login controller for the redirect upon login:

```
// controllers/auth.php Line 30
function login()
{
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_admin()) {
        redirect('admin');
    } elseif ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('user');
    }
    // Rest of code stays untouched...
}
```

Then have your admin controller always check for `$this->tank_auth->is_admin()`.

This is the *shortest* route I can offer to achieve your goals - probably not the *best*, but you might be interested in [Ion_Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) which does handle user groups by default.

Comment: sounds like the best solution.

Comment: I'm still surprised there aren't more authentication libraries available for CI, but then again not that surprised because everyone's needs are different. I prefer to roll my own. I don't like how Tank_Auth reads straight from the session for username, etc. For example if I deactivate a user, I want them booted immediately.

Comment: I agree, however like you say everyone has different needs.  Personally I dont like CI native AR I prefer to use php-activerecord therefore I needed to roll my own. I think most auth libs are outdated now.

Comment: thank you. worked! but now I'm using Ion Auth due the advantages.

Comment: If you use the 'remember me' feature of tank_auth, you will also need to modify the autologin function, where it's sets the session data, add is_admin there too.